# reusable component

Tags: iphone, ios4

I want to learn how to create reusable component so that I can use them anywhere. I want to create a ScrollView that i can use in any file (.m) by its object.any guidance ?

Comment: ScrollView is already part of UI components (see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html). Why you want to rewrite that buddy?

Comment: @hemant: actually I want to make some global functionality. I want to make a class of scroll view for specific Rect and want to use in multiple places(.m file). so thats y..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create an UIView Class , keep that one as global.

In that

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    // Initialization code.
  }

  //code for UISCrollview with frame.
  return self;
}
```

now just call this class where you want to put a scrollview , this will work as globally, you need to call this call with it's object and what ever code you have written it will be implemented.

Hope this is what you were needed.

Comment: thanks... let me know 1 more thing can I use like            @interface MyScroll : UIScrollView{}   ?

Comment: NO you cannot. you need to create these class object where you want to call the scrollview and then using that object you can use the same. the method which you are asking is not proper.

Comment: is there any to do like that ? so that I can create an object of MyScroll into any file.

Comment: just call class.h file in any other file where you want to use the global file and then create the object of global calss file ,  then you can use.